# change rows depending on the ordernumber in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating for my education-project a pizza-ordering website. With the help of the stackoverflow-community I've achieved already a lot - so thank you! But now I'm stuck and can't find any working solution to my problem.

## Question

How can I change the row color alternating (white / grey / white / grey ...) depending on the `ordernumber` in the database(mysqli)? The `ordernumber` can be in more than one row, so I can not simple change the color row by row.

I've tried with jquery, but this works only if the ordering numbers remain always in the list (even/odd) ... if an order is cancelled, then it doesn't works anymore (see image with missing ordernumber 7)

Here is the code in jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var check = 0;
          
for(var i =0; i<= $("tr").length;i++){
          
$("tr").each(function(){
        
if(parseInt($(this).find("#bestnr").text())==check){
            
    if(check%2 == 0){
    
        $(this).css("background-color","white");    
    
    }else{
    
    $(this).css("background-color","#DCDCDC");    
    
    }
     
        }    

        });
          
          check +=1;

          }
        
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you literally just want to alternate row colours on output, you don't need to worry about the database/backend at all. With CSS3 you can use the *odd* and *even* selectors : `tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#e1e1e1; } tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#ffffff; }`

Comment: What is the logic here? Do you just want to make alternating rows white and grey? Or is this somehow dependent on data from the backend?

Comment: Wow! This went fast! The Problem with the alternating row-color is, that I want the "ordernumber" to define the color switch ... I've edited my post, because I couldn't upload a image ... maybe it's clearer, what i'm trying to achieve ...

Comment: It's not *actually* based on the order number then other than as a sort of grouping; e.g. first order white, next grey, then white etc... the number itself isn't really relevant? (which is why you can't use the modulo operator) If that's the case you probably just want a `previousOrder` variable defined as `0` outside the loop. Then loop through your order and do the output basing the row colour on whether the current order number is the same as the `previousOrder` variable. Update the `previousOrder` variable with the value of the current order number.

Comment: Exactly CD001, the number it's not really relevant ... I tried with the number, because I didn't find any other way ... but like you said ... first order white, next order grey ... the problem is that a order can be in multiple rows.

Comment: @CD001 ... that sounds perfect ... but sorry, I'm absolutely new to coding (started 2 months ago) and I'm reading your lines like "Okay, sounds cool ... but how do I do that!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're working with JQuery, something like this ought to do the trick - explanations in code comments.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // define the initial "previous order id" as 0 assuming
    // there will never be an order with id 0
    var previousOrderId = 0;
    var previousBgColour = '#dcdcdc';
    var thisBgColour;

    // loop the table rows
    $("tr").each(function() {

        // determine "this" row id (assuming bestnr is short for bestelnummer)
        // and that the text in that table cell *is* the order number
        // I've changed this to a class as an id HAS to be unique
        // you'll need to update your code to accommodate
        var thisOrderId = parseInt($(this).find(".bestnr").text());

        // define the background colour based on whether the order id has changed
        // if it has change it
        if(thisOrderId != previousOrderId) {
            thisBgColour = previousBgColour == '#dcdcdc' ? '#ffffff' : '#dcdcdc';
            previousBgColour = thisBgColour;
        }
        else {
            thisBgColour = previousBgColour;
        }
        $(this).css({'background-color' : thisBgColour});

        //update the previousOrderId to this id
        previousOrderId = thisOrderId;
    });
});
```

You're basically storing the previous order id and comparing it to the current order id - if the order id hasn't changed it'll use the *previous* background colour, if it has it'll flipflop it to the alternate colour.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I don't know why but I'm getting a Syntax-Error on this line:

$(this).css({'background-color', thisOrderId == previousOrderId ? "#ffffff" : "#dcdcdc"});

Like we say in switzerland: "Maybe I have tomatoes on my eyes" :D

Comment: Sorry - I just found a couple of "quirks" when actually running it ... I'll update the answer shortly

Comment: That *should* do it ... I've not really had enough coffee for JavaScript yet ... would have taken me half the time in PHP probably ;) @DanRodriguez

Answer (score 0):

If it is just alternating colors, you can use CSS directly and not worry about anything else:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { 
 background-color:white; 
} 
tr:nth-child(even) { 
 background-color:#DCDCDC; 
}
```

If this is somehow dependent on logic from the backend, we can look at adding a class in jQuery and adding colors to this class via CSS

Comment: Thanks Dustin ... the problem with odd and even is, that if a a ordernumber is cancelled, then there are even numbers in a row. What I want to achieve is that the "ordernumber" defines the color switch ... I've edited my post, because I couldn't upload a image ... maybe it's clearer, what i'm trying to achieve ...

Comment: So can your requirement be summed up like this:
"If the `ordernumber` is different from the previous one, then change the color?"